# What grammar form is "having started working?

Tags: grammar

What grammar structure is "having started working" in this sentence?

> Heading into the fight, there were questions as to how well Joshua and new trainer Robert Garcia had gelled, having only started working together this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Heading into the fight, there were questions as to how well Joshua and*
> *new trainer Robert Garcia had gelled,* [*having only started working*
> *together this year*].

"Having only started working ..." is a gerund-participial subordinate clause (perfect tense) functioning as an adjunct in clause structure. Its semantic category is that of 'implicated reason': it gives the reason for the matrix situation.

Note that strictly speaking since the adjunct contains three verbs, there are three clauses: a matrix clause (the adjunct as a whole) and two subordinate clauses. For the sake of simplicity, though, you can think of "having started working" as a verb group.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It's clear now.